# How can I calculate and compare averages in a data set with different sample sizes?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I have a data set with about 1 million rows of data.

The most important fields are the id, the date_time, the customer and the score.

- Firstly I want to calculate the mean score for each customer (straightforward) but I want to consider the count of the score against each customer. Eg Customer A has an average score of 0.3 based off 10000 records, but customer B has an average of 0.8 based off 100 records. Sure the mean of the customer B is higher, but it is based off a lower sample size. How can I compare averages between customers accurately? Is it the mean that I need to be considering?
- Secondly, I have calculated the standard deviation of the whole data set to be 0.058, the mean is 0.00457. Is this a high st deviation or a low st deviation. Do we compare the st deviation to the mean, in which case is this a high st deviation (data points far from mean)?

Comment: you can look at the confidence intervals of the mean.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response, could you explain this in context of my data set please? Im not sure how to approach working out the CI or what that would mean according to the data i have